# How can I solve this problem of access violation when calling TThread's Inherited Create?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, access-violation

In Delphi 10.3 I'm creating a subclass of TThread. On creating the subclass I get an access violation exception.

The violation occurs in System.Classes' TThread.Create when 'FSuspended := not FExternalThread;' is being executed.

This is the code that gives the error.

```
unit TestThread;

interface

uses System.Classes;

type

  TTestThread = class(TThread)

  private

  protected
    procedure Execute; override;

  public
    constructor Create();
    destructor Destroy(); override;
  end;

procedure TestThreadClick();

implementation

constructor TTestThread.Create();
begin
  //inherited;
  //inherited Create;
  inherited Create(True);
  FreeOnTerminate := False;
end;

destructor TTestThread.Destroy();
begin
end;

procedure TTestThread.Execute;
begin
end;

procedure TestThreadClick();
var
  TestThread: TTestThread;
begin
  TestThread.Create();
  TestThread.Start();
  TestThread.Destroy();
end;

end.
```

The instructions *inherited*;, *inherited Create;*, *inherited Create(True);* all give the access violation.

If i override Create with *constructor Create(); **override**;* the compiler gives *E2170 Cannot override a non-virtual method*, so that's not the solution.

Anyone knowing what's the problem here?

Comment: `TestThread.Create();` is not correct. `TestThread := TTestThread.Create;` would be the right way to call the constructor.

Comment: Oops. Ofcourse. **Thank you.**

Comment: And you should explicitly `WaitFor()` the thread before `Destroy`'ing it. It is not good to let the `TThread` destructor wait on the thread for you, that is known to be very problematic.

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the addition.